# Unable to segue tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, nsindexpath

I am trying to create a Tableview app and here is my code, I am unable to segue due to an error saying cvc.college = colleges[indexPath.row] saying cannot assign value of type 'string' to 'College!'
What do i do?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!




    var colleges = ["Harper","UofI","Florida State University"]







    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        var college1 = College(name: "Harper", state: "IL", population: "25,000+")
        var college2 = College(name: "UofI", state: "IL", population: "44,000+")
        var college3 = College(name: "Florida State University", state: "Fl", population:"40,000+")
        var colleges = [college1 , college2, college3]



    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colleges.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.textLabel!.text = colleges[indexPath.row]
        return myCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            colleges.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
            let college = colleges[indexPath.row]

        }

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath:     IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let college = colleges[sourceIndexPath.row ]
        colleges.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        colleges.insert(college, at: destinationIndexPath.row)


    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var cvc = segue.destination as! CollegeViewController
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
            let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

            cvc.college = colleges[indexPath.row]

        }

}
```

heres my code for CollegeViewController

```
 class CollegeViewController: UIViewController {
var college : College!
@IBAction func onTappedSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    college.name = collegeText.text!
    college.state = stateText.text!
    college.population = populationText.text!


}
@IBOutlet weak var collegeText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var populationText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var stateText: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 collegeText.text = college.name
 stateText.text = college.state
 populationText.text = String(college.population)


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to put `moveRowAt` and `prepareForSegue` methods inside the `ViewController` class because currently you have added it as outside the class.

After that your `prepareForSegue` like this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var cvc = segue.destination as! CollegeViewController
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
       let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

         cvc.college = colleges[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Whole code would be like this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var colleges = ["Harper","UofI","Florida State University"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colleges.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.textLabel!.text = colleges[indexPath.row]
        return myCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            colleges.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }            
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let college = colleges[sourceIndexPath.row ]
        colleges.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        colleges.insert(college, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var cvc = segue.destination as! CollegeViewController
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
            let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

            cvc.college = colleges[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is no code of `self.performSegue`, so I'm considering that you have created segue from `UITableViewCell` to `CollegeViewController`.

Comment: What would happen to colleges down below that listed the population and state? would  they have to be deleted?

Comment: @AdrianAtun Its up to you because current you are not using it, If you are setting datasource array with that `colleges` array of custom object then it is batter if you add that array also inside your ViewController class.

Comment: @AdrianAtun Have you try like my answer is it working after that are you able to pass data in `CollegeViewController`?

Comment: Not yet, my mac is in school, I use windows for my personal computer.

Comment: @AdrianAtun Ok when you tried it, respond here is it working or not.

Comment: im on my mac right now and trying to input the code, Hopefully it works!

Comment: @AdrianAtun If my solution works then consider to accept my solution and mark as correct. If you don't know how to accept answer here check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346600

Comment: I put in the end code but the problem is in Let indexPath = Self.myTableView.indexpath(for: cell) Self is said to be use of unresolved identifier "self"

Comment: @AdrianAtun Edit your question with your code that you are trying currently. So I understand problem behind this error.

Comment: @AdrianAtun In `CollegeViewController` change type of college to String from `College` because your array is type of String.